# matrix inside data.frame in R or other nested structure

Tags: r, multidimensional-array, dataframe, distance, knn

I need to construct a data structure in R containing a `matrix` (or `data.frame`) for each observation. Ideally, it would be a `matrix` inside a `data.frame`. So far, I can only think of nested lists, to achieve it, but then I am afraid to have poor performance.

## Example

For example, for the data.frame element

```
df <- data.frame(start=c("A", "B", "C"), end=c("A", "B", "C"))
```

I would like to add a column containing a matrix in each cell (resulting from the distance function). For example for element start=="A", end=="B" it could be the matrix (or data.frame)

```
haversineStart haversineEnd tripLengthDiff startCountry endCountry truckDiff
160.5408     308.1947        198.745            1          1         1
152.4168     308.1947         20.710            1          1         1
273.7599    2228.3508       2903.212            0          1         1
```

Theoretically, it would just be some kind of 3d data structure. In Python, it would be list of lists containing a `NumPy`-array. Is something like that possible in R?

## Background

I want to perform knn with a custom distance function and I need to normalize the distances before performing the `knn`

Answer (score 1):

If you already have nested list:

```
d <- list(
    a = list(matrix(rnorm(4), 2, 2), matrix(rnorm(4), 2, 2), matrix(rnorm(4), 2, 2)),
    b = list(matrix(rnorm(4), 2, 2), matrix(rnorm(4), 2, 2), matrix(rnorm(4), 2, 2))
)
```

you can convert it do data.frame easily, as data.frame is still list:

```
class(d) <- 'data.frame'
colnames(d) <- c('A', 'B')
rownames(d) <- c('A', 'B', 'C')

d['A', 'B']

# [[1]]
#            [,1]       [,2]
# [1,] -0.6326935 -1.1181986
# [2,] -1.3066515  0.6672159
```

Answer (score 1):

Just assign a list of matrices to a new column in the data.frame. For example, assuming `df` from the question:

```
m <- matrix(c(1, 12, 3, 14), 2)
df$mat <- list(m, 2*m, 3*m) # test list
```

so

```
> df$mat[[1]]
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    3
[2,]   12   14

> df[[1, "mat"]]
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    3
[2,]   12   14

> transform(df, det = sapply(mat, det))
  start end          mat  det
1     A   A 1, 12, 3, 14  -22
2     B   B 2, 24, 6, 28  -88
3     C   C 3, 36, 9, 42 -198
```